# React remove event listener on ref that is also a state value (performance)

Tags: reactjs, events, react-hooks

I have an HTML audio element that lives in redux state (I know, Its like this so it can be played / paused from reducers).

That audio is assigned to a `useRef`.

I have a `useEffect` that adds and removes a `timeupdate` event listener.

The

```
const {
    isPlaying: { audio, trackNum, playing },
  } = useSelector((state) => state.directory_reducer);

  const audioRef = useRef(audio);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (audio && !spotify_loading) {
      audioRef.current = audio;
      audioRef.current.addEventListener('timeupdate', getProgress);
    }
    return () => {
      setProgressPercent(0);
      setProgressTime(`0:00`);
      !firstRender && audioRef.current.removeEventListener(
        'timeupdate',
        getProgress
      );
    };
  }, [audio]);
```

The problem is that after stopping and starting different tracks the page interaction becomes sluggish, it seems like I am not removing the listeners correctly. I am suspicious that it is because I am passing a state value to a ref which is not something I have seen anyone do. I am also wondering if the culprit is related to the following:

```
The returned object will persist for the full lifetime of the component.
...
This works because useRef() creates a plain JavaScript object. The only difference 
between useRef() and creating a {current: ...} object yourself is that useRef will give
you the same ref object on every render.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use empty array instead of `[audio]` so the `removeEventListener` will trigger when the component is released

```js
useEffect(()=> {


},[])
```